# Add a vanilla event listener?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component that is wrapping another (3rd party) component.

I'm targeting an element in this 3rd party component and adding an event listener.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.holder button').forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('a');
    }, false);
});
```

I've got the above code in mounted in my parent component, but no events seem to be attached.

Comment: it should be caused by when parent component mounted, there is nothing found for `document.querySelectorAll('.holder button')`.

Comment: Thanks - but why?

Comment: When you use the `mounted()` life cycle hook, there is no guarantee that all child components will also be mounted. Therefore what is happening is the piece of code that is dependent on the `button` component it being called before the component is actually rendered. It is recommended that you use the `this.$nextTick()` method to ensure that the entire view is rendered before you code fires. [VueJS Resource](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted)

Comment: one quick solution: hook `updated()` then remove/add your event listener(if not remove first, it will bind the event again and again)

Answer (score 1):

The `mounted` lifecycle hook is the right spot and the `this.$nextTick()` method as well but if all this does not work you should use a "ready"-callback of the 3rd Party.

- The most partys have a callback that indicates when they are ready to work. This callback should add your event listener.
- Another way is to mount the 3rd Party in your `mounted`-hook and after that procedure you add the Listeners inside of a `$nextTick()`. Then your listener is added after the plugin is initialised AND the plugin has one vue-render period time to add its elements properly to the DOM.

  ```
  mounted () {
    // first mount your 3rd party plugin on it's element
    $('#mountelement').plugin()

    this.$nextTick(()=>{
      document.querySelectorAll('.holder button').forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
          console.log('a');
        }, false);
      });
    })
  }
  ```

If your 3rd Party needs a request or is very small you should go the
   first way.

Comment: `this.$nextTick` expects a function, not undefined. In the case you pass undefined, it returns a promise that you should wait for, if you want to run code after the next tick